# Where can I find ToolbarPlacement attribute of TabbedPage?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, tabbedpage

I'm trying to locate the Tabbing bar in the bottom of the screen in android and I already did in the C# code behind but I'm just wondering how to do that in the .xaml code?

I've added the `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific` namespace but can't find the `ToolbarPlacement` attribute to set it to `"Bottom"` like is shown in the image below.

[image]

So is there a way to set it in the xaml code?

Comment: Please check the Xamarin.Forms version, this feature is available from X.F 3.1.

Comment: Thanks for help but my version is X.F 3.4 and it does not work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see your `Xamarin.Forms` package is not up to date because of which you are unable to use that feature. Just update the `Xamarin.Forms` package to 3+ and I think that should solve your issue.

Feel free to revert in case of queries

**Update:**

Try adding the following lines manually and try if it works:

```
xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

Comment: Thanks for help but my version is X.F 3.4 and it does not work though.

Comment: I've tried that before but I got a "property 'ToolbarPlacement' was not found in type 'TabbedPage'" error message but when you told me to try that (of course I got same error) but when I rebuild the project surprisingly, it's built succeeded and it works too! thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Toolbar Placement**

It is possible to get these tabs at the bottom with a specific platform:

**On XAML code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" >
```

The blue line indicates that ToolbarPlacement or others cannot be found. It is a problem of intelligisense because they are not properties and are real constructive arguments. **don't worry, they work great!**

**Or in C# code behind:**

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
```

**you can also use these properties to customize the bar at the bottom**

```
BarBackgroundColor="#2196F3"
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Wihte"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#66FFFFFF"
BarTextColor="White"
```

Answer (score 0):

Customizations is changed:

From:
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Wihte"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#66FFFFFF"

To:
SelectedTabColor="White"
UnselectedTabColor="#66FFFFFF"

Comment: Hey, how this is different from Maher Ben answer? (Feb 29)