# Why ToolbarPlacement doesn't work anymore in xaml

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin and I wanted to put my TabbedPage in the bottom in Xaml by using this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/tabbedpage-toolbar-placement-color
Then, when it didn't work, I tried to rebuild the project like suggested in this stackoverflow question:
[Where can I find ToolbarPlacement attribute of TabbedPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53542231/where-can-i-find-toolbarplacement-attribute-of-tabbedpage)

I saw some people using a old nugget package, but I don't really want to use it, especially if there is a native way of doing it.

Xamarin forms version : 4.1.0.555618
Android version : 9

I hope there is someone that have the same problem as me,

Thank you in advance,

halonico,

Answer (score 1):

Setting the placement and color of the toolbar on a TabbedPage, you just add the following code:

```
 xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#666666"
android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Red"
android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
```

Although there are still many mistakes, you don't meed to  worry about these, you try to clean your project, then build your project directly, you will see it works fine.

Comment: That's interesting and weird at the same time.  Yes it's true that it works, but why Microsoft doesn't fix it, and removed almost every documentation about it.

Thank you for your answer!